# Create Efficient Query in PostgreSQL and Consolidate Statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please excuse me if this is trivial - I am new to using PostGRESQL. I am given two
tables:

```
CREATE TABLE group_users (
  user_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id int NOT NULL,
  join_time timestamp NOT NULL,
  member_rank enum('l','a','m') DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE interactions (
  interactionid int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  target_user_id int NOT NULL,
  start_time timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

I now have to answer the question:

What is the percentage of interactions between: users in different groups, 
users in groups vs. those not in any group, and users in the same 
group?

This is my query - I do, however, have to consolidate it into one query.

My questions
are:

1. For the query below is there a more efficient way to do this in PostGRESQL?
2. What would be the most efficient way to make this one query?

-- Map user_ids to group_ids with interaction information

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE group_interaction_information AS
SELECT 
a.interactionid,
a.user_id, 
b.group_id, 
a.target_user_id, 
c.group_id AS target_group_id
FROM interactions a
LEFT JOIN
group_users b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN
group_users c
ON a.target_user_id = c.user_id;
```

-- Percentage of interactions of users in difference groups

```
select 
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information
where group_id != target_group_id and group_id is not null 
and target_group_id is not null)/(select count(*) from group_interaction_information)::float;
```

-- Percentage of interactions from users in groups

```
select 
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information
where group_id is not null)/
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information)::float;
```

-- Percentage of interactions from users not in a group

```
select
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information where group_id is null)/
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information)::float;
```

-- Percentage of interactions from users in the same group

```
select 
(select count(*) from group_interaction_information
where group_id = target_group_id and group_id is not null 
and target_group_id is not null)/(select count(*) from group_interaction_information)::float;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to combine your queries is with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    count(case when group_id <> target_group_id then 1 end) / count(*)::float,
    count(case when group_id is not null then 1 end) / count(*)::float,
    count(case when group_id is null then 1 end) / count(*)::float,
    count(case when group_id = target_group_id then 1 end) / count(*)::float
from group_interaction_information
```

By the way, `a = b` will never be true if one or both of the columns are null, so if you have a condition like `group_id = target_group_id` it's not necessary to specify `and target_group_id is not null`. The same applies to `a <> b`. To test run `select null = null, null <> null, 'a' <> null` - these will all result in `null`.

Comment: @RDizzl3 glad I could help :)